# How to crop image roundedly in android studio ?

Tags: android

How to crop image roundedly in android studio ? because i have to crop picture of eyeball for my thesis. Hope somebody help me

Comment: I see lots of answers when I search for `android crop round image site:stackoverflow.com` on Google. Since it is unclear what you mean by "crop" here (have the user crop an image? make an `ImageView` round? something else?), you may have better luck using a search engine and searching for existing answers that address your concern.

Comment: so i'm going to make "liver disease detection using iris based on android",so i need to crop the picture of iris roundedly so that rounded-crop picture can be process in the database. sorry if i'm not good explaining it in english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)